# Unable to link MongoDB C Driver?

Tags: c, mongodb, linker

I compiled the Mongo C Driver using the instructions at:

> http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/building.html

With the command:

> scons --m32 --standard-env

I am now trying to use the driver in another project, on the same machine I used to compiled the driver. My Environment is Windows 7 (64 bit) using Visual Studio 2008 (SP1) Standard. I am not, however using the IDE, but a custom makefile via command prompt.

I added it to my projects' makefile pointing INCLUDE to the mongo.h folder
I added it to my project's makefile pointing LIBS to the mongoc.lib folder

My code is:

```
#include "blakserv.h"

mongo conn;

void InitMongo()
{
    mongo_init( &conn );
    mongo_client( &conn, "127.0.0.1", 27017 );
}

void EndMongo()
{
    mongo_destroy( &conn );
}
```

The link command:

```
link -nologo    debug\main.obj debug\loadkod.obj debug\class.obj debug\message.obj debug\object.obj debug\sendmsg.obj debug\roofile.obj debug\bufpool.obj debug\ccode.obj debug\channel.obj debug\list.obj debug\timer.obj debug\session.obj debug\loadrsc.obj debug\blakres.obj debug\roomdata.obj debug\commcli.obj debug\string.obj debug\async.obj debug\loadgame.obj debug\game.obj debug\term.obj debug\account.obj debug\loadacco.obj debug\saveacco.obj debug\savestr.obj debug\loadstr.obj debug\nameid.obj debug\time.obj debug\dllist.obj debug\trysync.obj debug\saveall.obj debug\loadall.obj debug\synched.obj debug\motd.obj debug\admin.obj debug\garbage.obj debug\kodbase.obj debug\savegame.obj debug\user.obj debug\system.obj debug\resync.obj debug\gamelock.obj debug\config.obj debug\apndfile.obj debug\admincons.obj debug\builtin.obj debug\version.obj debug\systimer.obj debug\memory.obj debug\interface.obj debug\intrlock.obj debug\chanbuf.obj debug\debug.obj debug\saversc.obj debug\adminfn.obj debug\table.obj debug\parsecli.obj debug\rscload.obj debug\crc.obj debug\md5.obj debug\maintenance.obj debug\block.obj debug\stringinthash.obj debug\intstringhash.obj debug\files.obj debug\sprocket.obj debug\database.obj debug\blakmongo.obj debug\blakserv.res gdi32.lib user32.lib wsock32.lib winmm.lib comctl32.liblibmysql.lib mongoc.lib bson.lib -OUT:debug\blakserv.exe /STACK:0x180000 /map /debug /subsystem:windows -nologo /debug /machine:ix86
```

The link errors:

```
blakmongo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_@mongo_client@12
blakmongo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_@mongo_init@4
blakmongo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_@mongo_destroy@4
debug\blakserv.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

The link command clearly shows `mongoc.lib` and I have used dumpbin to dump the .lib's headers to a file, which clearly shows the needed objects are within.

I have also tried compiling the MongoDB driver as 32 vs 64 bit, but receive the same result.

I feel like the answer is something very simple and I'm glossing right over it.

This is all for an open source project, located at: https://github.com/Daenks/Meridian59_103

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to apologize for the state of the C Driver documentation, we've actually done a full re-write, but haven't had a chance to update the docs on the website.

You're going to be much better off looking at: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver.  The build system is more modern (cmake based for windows, autotools everywhere else) and we even have binaries available for win64.  In addition to getting updates, it's nearly at feature parity with the other drivers (2.6 features included).

Take a look at it and see if it helps out.